# White powder (?) on the leaves pf my apple tree sapling

Tags: plant-health, leaves, indoors

My (indoors) apple tree sapling has some white powder/decoloration on its leaves. I have no idea what causes this, how serious it is, and what I can or should do.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have an infestation of some insect or other, maybe thrips or blackfly, possibly, I cannot see clearly what they are even under magnification. The insects are visible on the top left leaf in the picture; you  could examine them with a magnifying glass to try to determine precisely what they are. The deposits on the other leaves are likely connected to this infestation. You can try spraying with insecticide or something like neem oil, but apple trees do not do well indoors, they need to be outside, so you may find any problems like this hard to control. If you want to move it outdoors, depending where you are and the weather at this time, it will need to be gradually acclimatised to outdoor temperatures first.

Answer (score 2):

Some sort of mildew (a fungus) has infested those leaves. You might try a fungicide listed for use on such, but it looks far too advanced to me for any effective chemical control. My pretty large apple tree at home once got that stuff one rainy Spring, and lost almost 100% of its leaves, but it eventually sprouted a new set.